# Why does time-ordering and derivation with respect to time commute?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

I have to proove that 
$$\hat{U}(t,t_{0})=T\bigg\{\mathrm{exp}\bigg (\int_{t_{0}}^{t}\hat{H}_{\mathrm{int}}^{I}(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau\bigg )\bigg\}$$

is a solution of the Schrödinger equation:

$$i\partial_{t}\hat{U}(t,t_{0})=\hat{H}_{\mathrm{int}}^{I}\hat{U}(t,t_{0})$$

The proof that this is the case is very simple, when I am allowed to interchange the time-ordering operator with the time derivative....but why am I allowed to do this?

Comment: Hint: you can insert a small parameter $\lambda$ in front of $H_\text{int}$ and prove this order by order in $\lambda$.

Comment: Observe (for later maybe) that no time ordering operator exists. It is more like a prescription read together with the exp.

Answer (score 1):

The formal expression of the Dyson series is:
$\hat U(t, t_0) = T \{ exp [ -i \int_{t_0}^t dt' \hat H_{int}(t') ] \}$
where $T\{\}$ is the time-ordering operator.

To demonstrate that it is the solution to the Schroedinger equation you are allowed to take the derivative as the time-ordering just places the operators within the brackets in order regardless of whether they commute or not.